# How to temporarily store recordset result in client for use to reduce DB calls

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on Excel VBA development recently, I found the recordset retrieved from database will not be available after Connection.Close.  Thus, everytime I need some master data, I need to call DB to get it again.  That may have very bad impact on the performance.  I wonder **if there is some solution to store recordset temporarily in client before workbook close**, so I can use them without more DB calls.  BTW, I was a C# programmer before, and I used ADO.NET to handle the interaction with database.  One of the most difference between ADO and ADO.NET is dataset can support off-line query, but recordset needs the connection to be available, I think.

1) Can I get the recordset support off-line query? (Even the connection is closed, the data is still reachable.)
2) Solutions for temporarily storing DB query result before workbook close.
3) There are some collection type in C#, such as Dictionary, List, HashTable, does VBA have the similar data structure?

Answer (score 3):

Recordsets can be disconnected (and later reconnected) and kept in memory or saved to file as xml or a binary format. See the various methods and properties of a recordset.

> Saves the Recordset in a file or Stream object.

```
recordset.Save Destination, PersistFormat
```

> **Parameters**
>
> Destination
>
> Optional. A Variant that represents the complete path name of the file where the Recordset is to be saved, or a reference to a Stream object.
>
> **PersistFormat**

Optional. A PersistFormatEnum value that specifies the format in which the Recordset is to be saved (XML or ADTG). The default value is adPersistADTG.

**And from Help**

> One of the most powerful features found in ADO is the capability to open a client-side Recordset from a data source and then disconnect the Recordset from the data source. Once the Recordset has been disconnected, the connection to the data source can be closed, thereby releasing the resources on the server used to maintain it. You can continue to view and edit the data in the Recordset while it is disconnected and later reconnect to the data source and send your updates in batch mode.
>
> To disconnect a Recordset, open it with a cursor location of adUseClient, and then set the ActiveConnection property equal to Nothing. (C++ users should set the ActiveConnection equal to NULL to disconnect.)
>
> We will use a disconnected Recordset later in this section when we discuss Recordset persistence to address a scenario in which we need to have the data in a Recordset available to an application while the client computer is not connected to a network.

Comment: It seems really complicated.  Is there any simple solution without external files?  Such as public variables to store the result from database.

Answer (score 1):

You already have it in an object variable. It's not going anywhere while your program runs. It takes one line of code to disconnect. It takes one line of code to save to disk if you want it in future runs of your program, but you don't have to save it. Then one line to reconnect it.

Comment: The OP is asking a point-by-point question.  It would helpful to answer his questions likewise point by point.

Comment: I did, I wrote the line of code to save it in my OTHER answer (his point 2). I copied the part from Help that says what to do - Set Connection to Nothing (his point 1). Try reading entire pages.